# Git merge with a local branch but favour 1 branch

Tags: git

I have 2 branches: `main` and `new`. `new` has some new files and some old code that has been fixed in `main`. I want to merge either:

- `new` to `main` or
- `main` to `new`

but favour the code changes already exist in `main` and have the new files in `new`.

For example:

In `main`, I have:

```java
public abstract class Reservation {
    public Reservation(String accountNumber, String reservationNumber, Date checkIn, Date checkOut) {
    }
}
```

In `new` I have:

```java
public abstract class Reservation {
    public Reservation() {
    }
}
```

My goal is to have the `constructor` like in `main`.

I've tried:

- `git checkout --ours/theirs` or `git merge --strategy-option ours/theirs` but if I merge, the result will only show the code in `new` which I don't want.
- `git merge --strategy=ours new` from `main` but it doesn't do anything. The code is still the same and I don't have the new files from `new`.

What merge strategy allows me to achieve that? It's similar to having merge conflicts and I can pick which branch I can keep. However, in this case, git doesn't show any merge conflict to pick.

I'd like to see the diff like making a pull request on GitHub but using my local IDE (VSCode).

Comment: You can't. Git doesn't have a "favor" mode *except* when there are conflicts: if there are no conflicts, there's nothing to favor, and Git takes the change.

Comment: "new has some new files and some old code that has been fixed in main" do you mean the code was "old" while `new` was created?

Comment: Following your description, if the changes _were made in `main`_, and the place was not touched in `new`, then the merge should preserve the change from `main`, or mark a conflict if the place was touched in `new`. If it does not do it, there is something I'm missing.

Comment: I agree with @max630. Regardless of which way you (do a regular) merge, you should either get the constructor from `main` or have a conflict, unless you changed the constructor yourself by wiping out the parameters on the `new` branch. If you did that then you need to undo that change on the `new` branch.

Comment: It's not clear from the question- did you actually try doing a regular merge? For example, `git switch main` followed by `git merge new` ? (Or vice versa.)

Comment: @TTT that's what I expected. However, that's not the case, no matter how I merge it, the constructor in `main` will be replaced by the short constructor in `new`. `new` is a branch that is updated with new files and auto-generated code each time.

Comment: and the generated code isn't what I want to keep. I want to keep most of the code in `main` because it's modified with more accurate constructors and code. I only need a few files from `new` and some small changes in `new`. I assumed that --strategy=ours from `main` should do the trick but it doesn't.

Comment: @Viet does the `new` branch modify that constructor by blanking out the parameters?

Comment: Not just blanking out parameters. They're replaced by the auto-generated constructors from `new`. E.g.: in `main`: 
```
public Reservation(String accountNumber, String reservationNumber, Date checkIn, Date checkOut) {
// some code here
    }
``` 
will become: 
```
public Reservation() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in 2 steps. Make sure both branches have no uncommitted changes before it.

1: Fetch and merge new developments from remote main to local new, keeping new things in new.

```
git checkout new
git pull origin main
```

2: Merge remained newest developments from  new to main:

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main
git merge new
```

Be aware - if you touch the same areas at the same files in both main and new branches - it's a big chance you'll have conflicts that should be manually resolved. VSCode has tools for it.

Comment: Sorry, your solution doesn't work. Still the same result.

Comment: I update it a little bit - forgot to pull the main itself from the remote.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Same result.

Comment: Please try to debug it step by step. See which changes you see in the new branch after step1. Then what you see in main after pulling it from remote. And then what you see after the merge command.